# How to convert or transliterate HTML code for email formatting, into VBA using .HTMLBody?

Tags: html, vba, email

As a part of a minor VBA based automation built on my client's system, I would like to send a notification email every time a user modifies a certain entry on the spreadsheet.

The code is working and using .Body to generate an email is a simple fix. I would however like a more sophisticated approach with a more "in-depth" formatting to the email body using .HTMLBody.

I've looked up various resources but unable to get an easy method to convert my HTML code into VBA and store in a variable.

For example, I have the below code to generate a table in HTML (from wordtohtml.net). Converting this to VBA, I end up unsuccessful.

In short, I need the below text in VBA language stored in a string variable "MsgColorBody"

```html
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table style="border: none;border-collapse: collapse;width:404pt;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:white;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border:.5pt solid windowtext;background:#002060;height:14.4pt;width:59pt;">Reference</td>
            <td style="color:white;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border:.5pt solid windowtext;background:#002060;border-left:none;width:95pt;">Designation</td>
            <td style="color:white;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border:.5pt solid windowtext;background:#002060;border-left:none;width:250pt;">Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border:.5pt solid windowtext;height:23.4pt;border-top:none;">Gh123</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border:.5pt solid windowtext;border-top:none;border-left:none;">MT103</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;border:.5pt solid windowtext;border-top:none;border-left:none;">Recurring</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: This is how the table on the email body should look]

Comment: Put the html into a plain text file and read that into a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the HTML into a .Txt file, then read that into a variable when you need it. As per following - where the HTML was stored in C:\AnyFldr\MasterHTML.Txt

```
 dFile = "C:\AnyFldr\MasterHTML.Txt"
 FileHdr1 = FreeFile  ' Gets a numeric File Handle from the OS
 Open dFile For Input As #FileHdr1
    dContent = Input(VBA.LOF(FileHdr1), FileHdr1)
 Close #FileHdr1
```

Now dContent contains the HTML.

You might want to save the master record with markers for the data to be filled so you can replace those

Eg

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table style="border: none;border-collapse: collapse;width:404pt;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:white;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border:.5pt solid windowtext;background:#002060;height:14.4pt;width:59pt;">Reference</td>
            <td style="color:white;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border:.5pt solid windowtext;background:#002060;border-left:none;width:95pt;">Designation</td>
            <td style="color:white;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border:.5pt solid windowtext;background:#002060;border-left:none;width:250pt;">Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border:.5pt solid windowtext;height:23.4pt;border-top:none;">XXXFld1XXX</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border:.5pt solid windowtext;border-top:none;border-left:none;">XXXFld2XXX</td>
            <td style="color:black;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;border:.5pt solid windowtext;border-top:none;border-left:none;">XXXFld3XXX</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then simply use Replace to insert the values

```
dContents = Replace(dContents,"XXXFld1XXX","Gh123")
dContents = Replace(dContents,"XXXFld2XXX","MT103")
dContents = Replace(dContents,"XXXFld3XXX","Gh123")
```